# Looking for references on results on powers of primes dividing $y^n-1$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, divisibility

For a prime $p$ and positive integer $n$,
let $E(n,p)$ be the greatest $k$ such that
$p^k \mid n$, and $E(n,p) = 0$ if $p \nmid n$.
Let $E(n) = E(n, 2)$.

A number of years back,
I proved the following results, and wondered how well-known they were 
(all variables are positive integers):

1. If $y \ge 3$ is even and $n$ is even then
   $E(y^n-1) = E(n) + \max(E(y-1), E(y+1))$.
2. If $y$ is even and $p \mid y-1$, where $p$ is an odd prime,
   then
   $E(y^n-1,p) = E(n,p)+E(y-1,p)$.

Comment: From time to time I fiddled with that function E() in a broader context, and tried to make a nice article of my observations. For whatever reason I've a third or fourth version, but still is in the state of a sketchpad. If you anyway are interested to put your nose in it, it's here (http://go.helms-net.de/math/expdioph/CyclicSubgroups_work.pdf ). Perhaps you like that view into things and a new discussion makes me proceed on writing...

Comment: If we start a tag [question] we can pretty much tag everything with it. Sounds a bit redundant...

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://www.jstor.org/pss/4145132)?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty well-known, I think. Let $y=1+mp^k$, $p$ not dividing $m$, then expand $y^n-1=(1+mp^k)^n-1$ by the binomial theorem and look at the powers of $p$ in the terms.

Comment: That's essentially my proof for odd p, though the proof for p=2 is not the same.